# Query with elements depend

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a Postgres database and the table has three columns.

Each row represents an object:

```
key     value         element_id
--------------------------------
status  active        1
name    exampleName   1
city    exampleCity   1
```

I want to get every column `value` from row where `key=name` and if this element has `active` value in row with `key=status`.

In this example the result should be `exampleName` because this element is `active`. I tried to jus join but not usre how to solve it. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, I think you want this:

Try:

```
quantz=> select * from maya;
  key   |    value    | element_id 
--------+-------------+------------
 status | active      |          1
 name   | exampleName |          1
 city   | exampleCity |          1
(3 rows)


Select value 
From maya
WHERE key = 'name'
and element_id in (Select element_id from maya where key='status' and value='active')
;
    value    
-------------
 exampleName
(1 row)
```

Let me know if this works or not?

Comment: I pasted the working example in my machine. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you should join the table with itself:

```
SELECT names.value
FROM mytable AS names
JOIN mytable AS statuses USING(element_id)
WHERE names.key = 'name'
    AND statuses.key = 'status'
    AND statuses.value = 'active'
```

Comment: How should it impact on performance? Could you compare it with Mayank Porwal's solution?

Comment: I generally prefer JOINing than using sub-queries. Anyway, it heavily depends on the optimizer, on your data set and of course on the indices (I expect at least one on the `key` column). Ask PostgreSQL to analyse both queries and compare the results.